# Not able to get values of checkboxes populated through JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am associating checkbox with each row in table.
I want to get the selected checkboxes in the servlet.
I have populated the checkboxes like this:

```
<%int i=0; %>
<c:forEach items="${booklist}" var="book" varStatus="bookCount">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="bookSelected" id="bookSelected<%=i%>" value="<%=i%>"><c:out value="${book.title}"></c:out></td>
<%i=i+1%>
</C:forEach>
```

Servlet code is

```
String[] chks = request.getParameterValues("bookSelected");
```

The checkboxes do get displayed on screen but even though I select those checkboxes, the servlets variable `chks` gets a null value.

Comment: I am not using Struts

Answer (score 0):

You need to check few things here.

Are the check boxes within the form being submitted ?.

You are generating row for each check box. So, that table should be within form tag being submitted.

Now a days, you can check what parameters are submitted using tools like "Firebug" in the Firefox.

See if parameters getting passed with name "bookSelected".

[image]

Comment: No, Not all parameters are getting passed. I tried method getparameterValues() but it did not return parameter with bookSelected checkbox